# ng2-tree TreeModule is imported and an Unexpected value error is thrown - Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular

I get this error when the page loads.

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'TreeModule' imported by the module 'SharedModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

In shared module:

```
import { TreeModule } from 'ng2-tree';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    TreeModule,
    ...
  ],
  exports: [
    ...
  ],
  entryComponents: [,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ]
})
```

Angular version is 4.4.3, ng2-tree version is 2.0.0-rc.1. I'm new to Angular so I'm not sure which more details are relevant.